# Parsing information from web service with redundant data

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am working on an iPhone app that receives information from a php web service I wrote and then displays that information in a `UITextView`.

What I am retrieving are entries in a list.  Each entry may have multiple sub entries, but only 1 or 2 "related entries" for each main entry in the table.

I am facing two related issues and I am looking for some advice or best practices on how to overcome them.

First, based on lots of reading of posts, I design my databased and normalized it the best I can.  The drawback however, is that when I have perform a query with lots of joins, i get a table with lots of redundant data.  This poses a problem for me on the client side when I parse the information.  When I parse the data and display it, i end up with a lot of duplicate entries in my `UITextView`.

Second, I thought that a workaround maybe to create separate queries (a big no-no I know), and only retrieve the information once.  This solves my problem in theory, but creates a new one.  Since my app retrieves information asynchronously, the database calls I make separately don't display for obvious reasons.  Besides, this feels like a hack and not an elegant way to solve my original problem.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**

Lets say you have `NSArray` containing (1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,3,3,3) as you said you are retrieving entries as a list , and you have to remove the redundancy or you just have to select distinct list items, than you can simply do the following:

You can transform `NSArray` into set for achieving unique array

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:array];

NSArray *a = [set allObjects]; here a contains (1,2,3,4,5)
```

**Approach 2:**

If you have list of objects with properties for example:

```
Person(name,age,gender) name , age , gender are properties .
```

And you want to have objects with distinct name only , then you can do the following:

```
NSArray *mainList; //this is your all entries list.
NSArray *uniqueNames = [mainList valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.name"];
```

uniqueNames is the list of Persons with unique names. If you want to select on the basis of age then you can simply replace name by age like this :

```
NSArray *mainList; //this is your all entries list.
NSArray *uniqueAges = [mainList valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.age"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a good idea.  I need to check to make sure all of the non-redundant items that I care about in my array are unique.  I'll give it a tray and get back to you.

Comment: What you suggested ended up not working.  It didn't allow me to keep the rest of the entry's dictionary.  What I ended up doing is creating a `NSMutableArray` and every time I parsed an item I would add it to the array. At the same time, i would check to see if the item was already added.  This prevented me from parsing redundant items.